# react-select - How to ensure the default selected items aren't appearing in both dropdowns?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In react-select I am using the same options for both dropdown choices. If one dog is selected in one drop-down, then it shouldn't show in the other drop-down - which was working fine.

Now I have added default selected items, it's not working as exspected. In the first dropdown, 'Bulldog' should not be available to select. In the second dropdown, 'Chihuahua' should not be available to select, as they are both have already been selected (see on demo).

Its a fairly complicated UI and a bit out of my comfort zone. Any ideas on how to get this working?

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**Dropdown data & Component:**

```
export const dogOptions = [
  { value: 1, label: "Chihuahua", firstDropdown: true, secondDropdown: false },
  { value: 2, label: "Bulldog", firstDropdown: false, secondDropdown: true },
  { value: 3, label: "Dachshund", firstDropdown: true, secondDropdown: false },
  { value: 4, label: "Akita", firstDropdown: false, secondDropdown: false },
  { value: 5, label: "Lab", firstDropdown: false, secondDropdown: false }
];

export default () => {
  const [options1, setOption1] = React.useState(options);
  const [options2, setOption2] = React.useState(options);

  return (
    <>
      <p>First dropdown</p>
      <Select
        isMulti
        options={options1}
        defaultValue={options.filter((o) => o.firstDropdown === true)}
        onChange={(v1) => {
          setOption2(options.filter((o) => o.firstDropdown === true));
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ height: 30 }} />
      <p>Second dropdown</p>
      <Select
        isMulti
        options={options2}
        defaultValue={options.filter((o) => o.secondDropdown === true)}
        onChange={(v2, a) => {
          setOption1(options.filter((o1) => !v2.includes(o1)));
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: When I comment out the defaultValue logic, the second dropdown doesn't seem to work properly. With one dog selected in the first input, only two dogs show up for the second dropdown.
https://codesandbox.io/s/69649548-using-react-select-how-can-i-filter-the-dropdown-options-between-2-selects-forked-xfrjd?file=/example.tsx

Comment: @Dan Whoops realised the mistake and fixed the code. Can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an initialize callback in `useState` to set the initial options for both `Select`:

```
const [options1, setOption1] = React.useState(() =>
  options.filter((o) => o !== defaultValue2)
);
const [options2, setOption2] = React.useState(() =>
  options.filter((o) => o !== defaultValue1)
);
```

If both default values are the same, then it's not a valid state, you can detect and throw an exception using `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (defaultValue1 === defaultValue2 && defaultValue1 !== undefined) {
    throw new Error("defaultValue1 and defaultValue2 must not be the same");
  }
}, [defaultValue1, defaultValue2]);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]